# Lookup Array Formula to calculate difference

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Hoping to build an `ArrayFormula` that's clearly beyond what I understand, so please bear with me. I'm using the following formula to grab the value of the [Last Non-Empty Cell](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell) and subtract the value of the cell immediately above it.

```
=ArrayFormula((LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet3!A:A))),Sheet3!A:A))-INDEX(Sheet3!A:A, CountA(A:A)-2,1))
```

I'd like to use a `HLOOKUP` function to match names from a vertical list, to identify the last non-empty cell in the corresponding column. I'm able to get the correct value from the 'Names' column with the formula below, but not sure how to integrate this into the `ArrayFormula`.

```
=HLOOKUP(A4,Sheet3!A1:E30,1,FALSE)
```

A correct formula should retrieve the value in the last non-blank cell of a column containing the name in `'Data Test'!A:A`

Please see sample sheet for reference: [Data Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJKiDNPUWMMUbLLb-UDA6iRA2PBnlMHDsEB9vELe0Rk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand the data it is reasonable to assume that the range in each column is consecutive.

We will also have to calculate the subsidy change for everyone separately because some of these formulae do not work with ArrayFormulae.

This formula finds the last row of the respective column and the second to last row and subtracts the two, if there is an error (because we try to subtract a string for Eric) we use the last and only value.

```
=IFERROR(
OFFSET(
  Sheet3!$A$1, 
  COUNTA(OFFSET(Sheet3!$A$1, 0, MATCH($A2, Sheet3!$A$1:$E$1, 0) - 1, 1000)) - 1, 
  MATCH($A2, Sheet3!$A$1:$E$1, 0) - 1) - 
OFFSET(
  Sheet3!$A$1, 
  COUNTA(OFFSET(Sheet3!$A$1, 0, MATCH($A2, Sheet3!$A$1:$E$1, 0) - 1, 1000)) - 2, 
  MATCH($A2, Sheet3!$A$1:$E$1, 0) - 1),
OFFSET(
  Sheet3!$A$1, 
  COUNTA(OFFSET(Sheet3!$A$1, 0, MATCH($A2, Sheet3!$A$1:$E$1, 0) - 1, 1000)) - 1, 
  MATCH($A2, Sheet3!$A$1:$E$1, 0) - 1))
```

Comment: Thanks @Robin, but I'm hoping to use a formula that will prevent me from having to calculate separately for each name